# How to get like count, comment count and share count for specific post in Spring-Social-Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

i'm using spring social facebook, but not able to get numbeer of like count, comments count and shares count for a specific post.

I have a post id and I'm using
fallowing code snippet

```css
facebook.likeOperations().getLikes(MY_POST_ID);

facebook.commentOperations().getComment(MY_POST_ID);
```

I dint get any method to get share count

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Social Facebook

```
...
Facebook fb = new FacebookTemplate(fbToken, "your.fbapp.Namespace");
PagedList usersLikeThisPost = fb.likeOperations().getLikes(fbPostId);
Integer likes = usersLikeThisPost.size();
...
return likes;
```

Ref:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/current/apidocs/

```
PagedList<Reference> getLikes(String objectId)
```

Retrieves a list of references to users who have liked the specified object. Limited to 25 references. Pass the PagingParameters returned from PagedList.getNextPage() into getLikes(String, PagingParameters) to get the next page.